# Accepting text/xml for SOAP 1.2 in C#

Tags: c#, soap, .net-3.5

I have a .Net 3.5 WCF service that functions as a SOAP API. A Client has a requirement to now send SOAP 1.2 envelopes (soap:Envelope instead of soapenv:Envelope), but they still use text/xml as the content type of the request instead of application/soap+xml

Is it possible to adjust the service through configuration to accept this behavior, or would i need to create something like an HttpHandler to intercept the request and modify the content type? I am already using a custom Message Filter registered in the Dispatcher to cater for modifications to the Action, as a custom header is provided that i am reading and routing.

The current configuration of the web services looks like this:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior"
    name="BusinessService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingForBigArrays"
      contract="IMasterService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="/12" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="https12Binding"
      contract="IMasterService" behaviorConfiguration="crsBehavior">

    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

And the binding configuration is

```
      <customBinding>
    <binding name="https12Binding">
      <transactionFlow />

      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="myBindingForBigArrays" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my issue, and i am going to update this question for future reference and for anyone else who might come across this problem.

The trick to this is to register a new Text Encoding element to identify the type of messages this binding may accept.

Since the `<textMessageEncoding />` element can only really take SOAP11 (text/xml) and SOAP12 (application/soap+xml), registering a new custom element that can be configured even further is the most robust way to do this.

Microsoft has some sample code to perform this, which can easily be imported into a solution (i created a separate library to house this code for reference). This reference data can be found here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder), and the sample code [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459).

Once this code is implemented you can define a new textMessageEncoding element customTextMessageEncoding combination such as `<customTextMessageEncoding encoding="utf-8" mediaType="text/xml" messageVersion="Soap12" />`. Note that the reference link has incorrectly labelled the line above with **contentType** instead of **mediaType**. The combination above allowed me to register the binding with a SOAP 1.2 envelope, and a SOAP 1.1 content type.

Another thing to do is to use the mediaType instead to change the response type, and override the IsContentTypeSupported on the MessageEncoder to allow the service to respond on a different content type. this is also a requirement from the client, as unusual as it is. The service can now accept both text/xml and application/soap+xml (through the overrided method) and respond on the provided mediaType

In a nutshell the solution requires:

1. implement a custom encoder and encoder factory
2. Implement a binding element for a custom encoder
3. Use the custom binding configuration to integrate custom binding elements
4. Develop a custom configuration handler to allow file configuration (app.config or web.config) of the custom binding element
5. Register the new binding element in the web.config
6. Use the new binding element to configure the binding